# Slow jQuery animation on iPad2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, animation, safari

I'm currently building iPad-optimised website. I have some chunks of text that I should show/hide when user touches appropriate button. The text is inside of < p> tag. I use jQuery for toggling the visibility of the text:

```
$("my selector").toggle("fast");
```

But it is really choppy ... Is there some iOS specific way to do the animation, maybe another framework or something else ?

I don't think it should be **that** slow ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several animation scripts that targets iOS, but the basics are that you should use CSS animations instead, and more specifically the `translate3d` property (for positioning) that triggers the iOS hardware.

For toggling opacity, you can use a regular -webkit-transition and toggleClass, f.ex:

```
p { -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear; opacity:1 }
p.hide { opacity:0 }
```

and then:

```
$("my selector").toggleClass('hide');
```

I made a simple demo for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/rQFZd/

You can detect touch devices and serve css animation specifically to those that supports (and prefers) it.

EDIT: example of animating height: http://jsfiddle.net/rQFZd/1/. I’m not sure about iOS performance though, but I think it should be better than jQuery.

You can also add another container and then use translate3d to reposition the element instead of shrinking it, that should most certainly be smoother on iOS. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rQFZd/2/

Comment: thanks ! Can I animate height like that ? I mean, I would prefer that text slides up/down. I don't know if I've described it good. Here's example: http://jsfiddle.net/cNSPP/ Can this be done with CSS3 ?

Comment: Thanks! It's still a little choppy, but I guess it can't be better ... And now I see that I didn't press Update on my jsfiddle example, but you got it ;)

Comment: Is the second example using translate3d also choppy? http://jsfiddle.net/rQFZd/2/

Comment: Yeah, I've just tested it on my web site and it performs choppy as javascript ... I guess it could be because of my website ... I have few images that Safari resizes ... I'll try to get rid of these and see if anything happens

Comment: I've just tried using fadeToggle() instead of slideToggle(). It works better (I'd say perfect) ... So for some reason, moving elements up/down is slow ... I think I'll stick whit this solution